# Uncheck ToggleButton after some period of time

Tags: java, android, android-widget, togglebutton

I want my ToggleButton to be unchecked after some period of time when i check it. I am using Timer and TimerTask but my application always force close when i try to do this. This is the code:

```
public class Vjezba5Activity extends Activity {

TimerTask TimerTask11;
Timer timer1 = new Timer();

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final ToggleButton TB1 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
    TB1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (TB1.isChecked()){
                TimerTask11 = new TimerTask() {
                      public void run() {
                          TB1.setChecked(false);
                      }
                  };
                  timer1.schedule(TimerTask11, 1000);
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(Vjezba5Activity.this, "Uncheck", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I would use a handler. Then post the actions involved in unchecking the button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only update the UI from the main thread.

Try using a handler.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final ToggleButton TB1 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    TB1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (TB1.isChecked()){
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {
                         TB1.setChecked(false);
                    }
                }, 1000);
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(Vjezba5Activity.this, "Uncheck", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can I cancel this if I choose to dont uncheck ToggleButton at some point?

Comment: I think you can using handler.removeCallbacks(Runnable r). You will need to create the Runnable as local variable in the first line of the onClick method so you can refer to it in the else clause.