# setVisibility with sleep

Tags: android, visibility

I have this code:

```
result.setVisibility(0); 
//a lot of code

//OnClick......
result.setVisibility(8);
SystemClock.sleep(500);
result.setVisibility(0);
```

So when i click a button the textView disappears and reappears to show that the result is changed.
But instead the textView "result" don't disappear and remains always visible. Why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if the `setVisibility` function is at fault here. It appears that you are trying to sleep inside the UI code which happens to be a very commonplace mistake.

I am not sure but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9058179/uncheck-togglebutton-after-some-period-of-time) willl help you.

Also I would recommend the usage of the pre defined constants `VISIBLE` , `INVISIBLE` and `GONE` instead of the integers.

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

Because you tell the thread that need to update the ui to go to sleep...
You should use animations for this stuff.